# API to tell if a house is for sale, foreclosed, or not forsale

Tags: api, programming, real-estate, address

I'm developing an R (or SAS) decisioning engine that requires input for whether a home is either for sale, foreclosed, or not for sale. I have a list of 10K addresses and would like to be able to pass these addresses to the API one at a time and have the for sale status returned.

I have tried Zillow, which comes close to giving me what I need (getdeepcomps call includes last sale date), however the data returned does not give me a current view of the market status for the address.

Has anyone found an api that returns this info?

Comment: Couldn't you train on a past date? For example, 2 years ago from today. Then all properties with a sale date after can be considered on the market.

Comment: yes, I can train on past data however the model will need input on whether the house is for sale, foreclosed, or short sale for all future decisions (the market status of the house will be an independent variable and not the dependent variable in the model).